# R markdown , Duplicate chunk Error Occurs

Tags: r, r-markdown

Running this script in R markdown, and receive following error message, could you suggest what could cause it?

> Format: ioslides_presentation

**Lets Have a look of Observation data and Try to Find Problems!**

```
BWHA <- read.csv("BWHA_Point_Count_Cams_Data.csv")[,c(1,2,6:8,10,11)]
head(BWHA)
```

**Lets Have a look of Site Covariates data and Try to Find Problems!**

2300 Unique Location

```
Site_cov <- read.csv("site_cov.csv")
head(Site_cov)
```

**ERROR**

```
processing file: Untitled.Rmd
Error in parse_block(g[-1], g[1], params.src, markdown_mode) : 
  Duplicate chunk label 'setup', which has been used for the chunk:
BWHA <- read.csv("BWHA_Point_Count_Cams_Data.csv")[,c(1,2,6:8,10,11)]
head(BWHA)
Calls: <Anonymous> ... process_file -> split_file -> lapply -> FUN -> parse_block
Execution halted
```

Comment: Could you please copy and paste your complete script?

Comment: I assume that you labeled your chunks both `setup`, there must be unique, so if you rename them the error should go away.